# Calling the same ColdFusion component from different templates

Tags: coldfusion

In a.cfm I have:

```
<CFSET VerObj = New cfcomponents.VerFold.Ver_Users()>
<CFSET VerObj.Functiion_1(userid)>
```

In the next few templates, c.cfm, I need to call a different function within Ver_Users.cfc I can do:

```
<CFSET VerObj = New cfcomponents.VerFold.Ver_Users()> 
<CFSET VerObj.Function_2(userid)>
```

If I need to call the same cfc again from yet another template down the road and I keep doing this I think it is very awkward and repetitive? the purpose of using .cfc is so that I can reuse or call the functions by just doing:

```
 <CFSET VerObj,Function_1()> or calling Function_2
```

from anywhere without keep instantiating the cfc am I correct? is there any example on how to accomplish This?

Comment: How to you access `c.cfm`? Is it a new request or is it included from `a.cfm`?

Comment: It is a new request. For example along the road my application require to use one of the function within that same .cfc

Comment: It terms of awkwardness, it's a trade off.  Instead of a single line of code in each relevant .cfm file, you will have to add `application.` to scope the object variable every time you use it.

Answer (score 2):

Instantiating a component has a very small performance penalty. It is not false to re-instantiate it in different templates.

If you really want to cut away these few nanoseconds an bytes of memory you can instantiate the component one time at the onApplicationStart() event im your Application.cfc and store it in the application scope.

```
<cfset application.verUser = new cfcomponents.VerFold.Ver_Users()>
```

And then call the functions in your cfm like:

```
<cfset application.verUser.Function_1()>
```

Comment: Before adding it to the app scope, **be sure the cfc is thread safe**, otherwise, it can create bugs.

Answer (score 0):

@Rbt - you could create an Application.cfc that instantiates the Ver_Users component, and call application.Function1() and application.Function2() in your cfm files. You could create a session and use Session scope, or use Application scope which would treat it as a global, depending on how you want to use it.